# Mongodb in Docker container, bad shutdown now won't start: exit 100

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

One of the annoying things about running Mongodb with docker-compose is if you stop your docker-machine without first stopping the compose containers (eg if you're running a local dev copy and reboot your laptop...) then Mongo gets in a bad state.

When you try and start mongodb again it fails:

```
$ docker-compose logs mongodb
Attaching to dockerenvironment_mongodb_1
mongodb_1 | about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
mongodb_1 | forked process: 12
mongodb_1 | ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
```

The general advice for this seems to be 'delete the lock file'

However I can't do that because the container has stopped already, I can't exec into it.

If I do (i.e. start a fresh container)

```
$ docker-compose run mongodb
root@a65901f9fc3d:/# ls /data/db
root@a65901f9fc3d:/#
```

...there's no lock file to delete.

I have tried also

```
$ docker rm -v dockerenvironment_mongodb_1
```

but when I start it fails again with Exit 100

I don't know what else to try, can anyone help?

Comment: well, I just stopped and `docker rm -v` _all_ the other containers on that docker-machine... starting up again now mongodb works. why?

Comment: Could you please share part of your `docker-compose.yml` for MongoDB?

Comment: Where did you get the advice of `delete the lock file` ? MongoDB error code 100 is for uncaught exception, which could be other things. Without seeing the proper docker-compose logs it's hard to know. For example, it could be that there is already a running container occupying the same designated port number. i.e previous mongodb container. It would be useful to see your `docker-compose.yml` and also the output of `docker ps`

Comment: @WanBachtiar  docker-compose logs for the mongodb container are given in the question. `docker ps` does not show any other containers running

Comment: Could you post the output of `docker-compose.yml` ?